# What should my FQDN be?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet, hosts, fqdn

When I setup my server, the guide said to use ns1.domain.com, (both my nameservers are ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com). However, recently, I changed it to www.domain.com, and everything works.. However, should it be ns1.domain.com instead? Or does it not matter a whole lot?

From what I gather, I should use ns1.domain.com, not because www.domain.com works, but because ns1.domain.com references to server one, where if I had a second server, it'd be ns2.domain.com (although at the moment, both ns1 and ns2 point to one server)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that ns1 and www point to the same IP address, which is why it works. In this case, either will work for you. They don't have to point to the same IP though. In a single server environment like yours everything points to the same spot. Once you get two, then it'll start to matter.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks. :) One more question though. What's your opinion on how to do a multi-server setup (relating to hostnames and DNS setup)? Just so I know it in the future, just in case. :)

Comment: I usually name the servers whatever I want and then add `CNAME` s to set which services they run. So then I can have `mordor.domain.com` with `www.domain.com` as a CNAME pointing to it. This way if the function changes (or one of the functions is removed) I just need to delete CNAME (or add a new one). That's not so important if you have fully virtualised environment and have single-purpose VMs...